# Django 1.9: How to make a dynamic form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a model called Course:

```
class Course(models.Model):
   number_of_semesters = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   field = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   qualification = models.ForeignKey(Qualification, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to get a form in which you can input as many courses as the user wants from the webpage. How will I do this?

Comment: You need django formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I've looked into formsets already and I am already able to save more than one of the same model. My question is how do I prompt the user with more fields. (i.e A plus button that will add a new but same form of Course).

Comment: You literally want formsets, and some Javascript on top.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one, but I would recommend you to use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Although it is kind of tricky at first, you can use the ViewSets and Serializers to get multiple objects and save them in your database at once. (BTW, even though it is used for API's you can easily substitute the normal Django views with the ViewSets and use them as a standard).

I know this is not actually what you asked, but I have been developing in Django for a while now and I haven't been able to use the formsets in a clean way to save N objects without knowing N at first.

If you decide to go with my proposal, I would recommend you to read the following:

- Viewsets
- Serializers (they are basically the same as the DjangoForms)
- Nested Serializers (for rendering/creating/linking your ForeignKey instance)

  ```
  # SERIALIZER
  from rest_framework import serializers

  class QualificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Qualification
          fields = (
              # Insert the fields here, just like a form
          )

  class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      qualification = QualificationSerializer() # Nested serializer
      class Meta:
          model = Course
          fields = (
              'number_of_semesters', 'field', 'qualification',
          )
  ```

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do this is to not use formsets but to get creative with the prefix that you use to load a form with. For example the + button loads an empty form with a prefix based on a counter posted to the view (including a tag, something like "course-4", so you get the form with `SomeForm(request.POST, prefix="course-4")`). When it's time to validate/save the view you simply parse the prefixes (with a regex) from the POST and save a form for every one of them.

It seems like a bit more work than to simply use formsets but every time I've tried to use them I had to abandon them at some point because they didn't provide enough flexibility.